# Openmax on Android for H.264 decoder?

Tags: android, decode, h.264, decoder

I am starting to develop a sample code to run H.264 decoder based on OpenMax IL. The requirement is that the decoder should work fine on any chipest(like snapdragon, omap or others supporting OpenMax, I have got omap3 and qualcom samples, but I need a sample that could work on both omap3 and qualcom and others).

Any suggestion for a starter? Or any simple testing code for studying?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the bellagio - open max project ( I guess taken care by ST ) in the linux environment. This will give you openmax component and openmax IL test application.
Also, you can look into the Android - Stagefright code for your reference. You can have a list of decoders and one can use the decoder based on the list priority.

Regards, Vibgyor